# Simple JS, onclick change background color

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning from my book, it said that I could use the `onselect` event instead of a button to change the background color of the page. I thought this would be extremely simple by using:

```html
<select id="selColor" onselect="changeColor()">
```

and

```js
function changeColor() {
    var selColor = document.getElementById("selColor");
    var color = selColor.value;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

But it failed. I tried searching for it but I cannot find the error.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kL3Jz/2/

Comment: [here we go](http://jsfiddle.net/kL3Jz/4/). your code works fine you just have to select `no wrap - in <head>` option from fiddle!

Comment: What are the values of your select. Are they valid colour values?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/kL3Jz/6/

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two versions.

Comment: Are you sure that the variable "color" has really a valid color ?

Comment: @sebcap26 There is a difference of `no wrap- in <body>` option :)

Answer (score 1):

As the others have mentioned, use `onchange` instead of `onselect`. However, it's generally considered bad practice to use inline events in HTML. I suggest you to add the event handler in JavaScript instead.

**HTML**

```html
<h1>Please select a color</h1>

<fieldset>
    <select id="selectColor">
        <option value="#FFFFFF">White</option>
        <option value="#FF0000">Red</option>
        <option value="#FFCC00">Orange</option>
        <option value="#FFFF00">Yellow</option>
        <option value="#00FF00">Green</option>
        <option value="#0000FF">Blue</option>
        <option value="#663366">Indigo</option>
        <option value="#FF00FF">Violet</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
document.getElementById('selectColor').onchange = function () {
    document.body.style.background = this.value;
};
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/kL3Jz/18/

You should either wrap the JavaScript code in `window.onload = function () { ... }` or put the `<script>` tag at the end of `<body>`, just before the closing tag.

Answer (score -1):

try to say `onchange` at the place of `onselect`.

```
<select id = "selColor" onchange = "changeColor()">
```

In fiddle you have to select `No wrap-in  <head>` also.

Comment: why? How does this change anything.

Comment: I have added in a file and checked.

Comment: @Liam In fiddle we've to select No wrap-in  <head>.

Comment: [this works perfectly fine with on onselect](http://jsfiddle.net/kL3Jz/6/) changing the event to onchange has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

just use

```
<select id = "selColor"  onchange = "changeColor()">
```

instead of

```
<select id = "selColor" onselect = "changeColor()">
```

use same function

```
 function changeColor(){
        var selColor = document.getElementById("selColor");
        var color = selColor.value;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
      }
```

Comment: [this works perfectly fine with on onselect](http://jsfiddle.net/kL3Jz/6/) changing the event to onchange has no effect.